# Custom package library needs a dependency from project where is imported on

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have created a custom package library. This library has http package dependency defined in pubspec.yaml.

```
version: 0.0.1
author:
homepage:

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  http: ^0.12.0+4
```

I imported this custom library in another project. When I run this project, shows this error related with http package:

```
Compiler message:
Error: Could not resolve the package 'http' in 'package:http/http.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'http_parser' in 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart'.
../xxxxx/lib/src/network/base/http_request.dart:4:8: Error: Not found: 'package:http/http.dart'
import 'package:http/http.dart';
```

I don't understand why need to import this package dependency in project if this http package is used only in custom library.

Find below the custom library structure and main dart file:

[image]

Comment: add http dependency to `dependencies:` not `dev_dependencies:`

Comment: Yes!! This was the solution. Thanks mate!!!

Answer (score 0):

As @Eugene said, the solution was move **http** dependency to `dependencies:` section instead `dev_dependencies:` section

Thanks a lot @Eugene